# calling function that is in the parent page from inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have deployed an app that is using iframes.

In one of the pages I have called `parent.functionname()`

The problem is, this application is shown in an iframe in a different domain.
So this line `parent.functionname()` is trying to call the main iframe's function which is not possible due to cross domain security policy.

How can i have this `parent.functionname()` call the function that is in the main home page of my application?

I need not access function in the parent iframe that is in the other domain, but I need to specify that the function is in immediate iframe and not the iframe containing that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: I need not access function in the parent iframe that is in the other domain, but I need to specify that the function is in immediate iframe and not the iframe containing that